# in pygame i have that problem: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, pygame

```
class Nave(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self):
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.image = pygame.image.load('images/nave.png')
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.rect.centerx = width / 2
      self.rect.centery = height / 2 
      self.speed = [0,0]

   def move(self,time,keys):
      if self.rect.right >= 0 :
         if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.centerx += self.speed * time 
      if self.rect.left <= width:
         if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.centerx -= self.speed * time
```

in the function move, in line 3 `"self.rect.centerx += self.speed * time"` console say me :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: So your `self.speed` field is a `list` and your `self.rect.centerx` is `int`. Shouldn't you somehow process your `self.speed` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.speed` is a list:

> ```py
> self.speed = [0,0]
> ```

You've to address an element of the list (e.g. `self.speed[0]` rather than `self.speed`):

```py
self.rect.centerx += self.speed[0] * time
```

Answer (score 1):

self.speed is a list you cant add list and int together.

`self.rect.centerx += self.speed[0] * time`

Use it like that.